# Extract coordinates of non-masked pixel centers from a raster

Tags: python, rasterio

I've a raster GeoTIFF file (1000x1000x1) with one binary band (it's a mask taking either 0 or 255 as a value for each pixel). I' using `rasterio` to read it:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.features import shapes

with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open('file_geo.tif') as src:
        image = src.read_masks(1)
        results = ({
            'properties': {'raster_value': v}, 'geometry': s}
            for i, (s,v) in enumerate(
                shapes(
                    image,
                    mask=None,
                    transform=src.transform)
                 )
        )
```

I extracted the coordinates of each pixel center into a (1'000'000x2) array using `np.meshgrid` and the right `Affine` elements of `src.meta`, namely the translation and the pixel steps in both X and Y direction, which leads to e.g. :

```py
points
array([[2238000.25, 1781999.75],
       [2238000.25, 1781999.25],
       [2238000.25, 1781998.75],
       ...
```

From that, how could I remove all "non-masked" pixels center coordinates in that list of points? Namely the points which are the center coordinates of any pixels with a value of 255 of the original raster?

I felt I'm on the wrong track for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you're creating `points`, but you'll want that array to be the same shape as the raster's array so values in the same position will correspond to each other.  Then you can create a boolean array from the raster mask and apply it to the points.

```
points = points.reshape((1000, 1000, 2))
mask = (image == 255)  # broadcasting, creates a boolean array
points_masked = points[mask]  # boolean indexing
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays